# What's wrong with printing from the List of classes?

Tags: c#, list, class

```
MyData data = new MyData { MyInt = 1, MyString = "Smith" };
MyData data1 = new MyData { MyInt = 3, MyString = "Wesson" };
MyData data2 = new MyData { MyInt = 2, MyString = "Colt" };
List<MyData> lst = new List<MyData>();
lst.Add(data);
lst.Add(data1);
lst.Add(data2);

Console.WriteLine("\nBefore sort:");
foreach (MyData MyInt in lst)
{
    Console.WriteLine((MyInt));
    Console.WriteLine(lst.ToString());
}
```

Just made simple list for practice, but in the output `i` have something wrong. [image]

Why it's shown that way? I've expected to get it's content. Two different ways gave me the same result. May be i'm wrong with list populating?

Comment: MyData needs to override the ToString function and provide the information you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

By default, your `MyData` class uses the implementation of `ToString()` it inherited from `System.Object`.  That function returns very generic information about the class - pretty much just the class name, and some limited information on any generic type parameters.

If you wish `ToString()` to display different information, you will need to override it yourself:

```
public override string ToString() 
{
    return String.Format("{0} {1}", MyInt, MyString);
}
```

Comment: Strange, still shows the same result. How properly i should write Console.WriteLine(lst.ToString()) - that part?

Comment: The `lst` variable is of type `List<MyData>`, which like `MyData` inherits its `ToString()` from `Object`.  `List<MyData>` won't use the `ToString()` from `MyData`, because it isn't a `MyData`.

Comment: So, i should place override somewhere else, or re-declare lst?

Comment: Don't use `ToString`, just print out the elements of the list.

Answer (score 1):

`MyInt` will be a varabile of type `MyData` - **not** the `MyInt` property of the object `MyData`.  Does the `MyData` class override `ToString()`?  That's what `Console.WriteLine` will be looking for when it tries to write the object - otherwise, it will use the default from `Object`, which is what you're seeing.

You probably want something more like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("\nBefore sort:");
foreach (MyData myData in lst)
{
    Console.WriteLine(myData.MyInt);
}
```

Which is instead writing the `MyInt` property of the `MyData` object.

If you want, you could override the `ToString` method like so in the `MyData` class/struct:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return MyInt.ToString(); // assuming you just want to see the MyInt property...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to output each MyData object, then you'll need to implement your own ToString method by overriding the default which is the result you're seeing above (displaying merely the object reference). You should also call your variables something different. Don't use MyInt in your for loop. Call it something sensible like data. Don't prefix your classes with My either. Bad practice.